# how to display the first word in the search table in the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, trim

hii every one in my iphone app i have a search screen & i have some entries in the search bar like sudha, tharanga and womens era  (some magazines )  suppose if we search cricket special,  it has to show the respective magazine

so i planned to have the table view data like follows

```
sudha  (cricket special, anna hazare special)
tharanga  (footbal special,x special)
womens era (some y special)
```

and while loading data to the table view  by trimming the all data which is present between the brackets ( ) and should i display remaining in the table view

so how can i trim the string in such a way that it should remove the data with in brackets and bracket symbols

so that my table view data should become like this

```
sudha  
tharanga 
womens era
```

, thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding trimming the string as per your requirement, I guess the simplest way to go about it is to use the `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` method as follows;

```
NSArray *anArray = [theFullString componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
```

Assuming `theFullString = @"womens era (some y special)"`, the resulting arrays first element would be as `@"womens era "`. I assume this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this nnstring method to get the desired result,

```
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

OR you can do that, first find bracket location,

```
int pointPos = -1;
for(int i=0; i<= [myString length]-1; i++){
    if ([myString characterAtIndex:i] == '(') {
        pointPos = i;
        break;
    }
}

NSString *finalString = [myString substringToIndex:pointPos];
```

Comment: The tricky part is finding the range. Care to explain how the poster can find it ?

Comment: Instead of iterating manually you could also use `[myString rangeOfString:@"("]` to get the position.